# Trying to use RegEx to parse a log file that consists of 3-line headers identifying multi-line text data

Tags: python, regex

The log file I am trying to parse (i.e., break up the text into individual data components) has the following format:

```
===================
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
===================

Line 1 of text
Line 2 of text 
...
Line last of text

===================
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
===================

Line 1 of text
Line 2 of text 
...
Line last of text

===================
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
===================

Line 1 of text
Line 2 of text 
...
Line last of text

....
```

I have attempted the following pattern with numerous variations, all without success:

```bash
(={19}\n(.*)\n={19}\n)(\n.*)+(?=={19})
```

The look-around at the end appears to be overridden by the preceding "+". Group 0 shows the entire file content; group 1 and 2 are correct; and group 3 (the multi-line text data) is empty.

Desired result is to create records with two fields:

```
Record1Field1:
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
Record1Field2:
Line 1 of text
Line 2 of text 
...
Line last of text

[etc]
```

In turn, data will then be imported into a database (actual application still to be determined).

Comment: Good suggestion; edited as requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the regex group to reduce the number of capturing groups + using non-greedy modifiers ([regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5WlLDt/1)):

```py
import re

text = """\
===================
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
===================

1 Line 1 of text
2 Line 2 of text
3 Line last of text

===================
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
===================

4 Line 1 of text
5 Line 2 of text
6 Line last of text

===================
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
===================

7 Line 1 of text
8 Line 2 of text
9 Line last of text"""


pat = r"={19}\n(.+?)\n={19}\s*(.+?)\s*(?=={19}|\Z)"

for title, body in re.findall(pat, text, flags=re.S):
    print(title)
    print(body)
    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
1 Line 1 of text
2 Line 2 of text
3 Line last of text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
4 Line 1 of text
5 Line 2 of text
6 Line last of text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DateTimeStamp - ShortSummaryOfEntry
7 Line 1 of text
8 Line 2 of text
9 Line last of text
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks much for your speedy response. Now I can go back and study what I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You have that result for group 3 because you are repeating a capture group, which will capture the result of the last iteration.

You could use 2 capture groups, and capture in group 2 all the lines that do not start with 19 equals signs using a negative lookahead:

For the match enable multiline with `re.M`

```
^={19}\n(?!={19}$)(.+)\n={19}((?:\n(?!={19}$).*)*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TCmrVp/1)

Comment: Excellent! Thanks much for your speedy response also. This gives me another way to view the problem.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the following would be sufficient.

```
^(.*\n)=+\s+((?:\d+ +.*\n)+)
```

The line preceding a line of equal signs is saved to capture group 1 and the string comprised of the following lines that begin with a digit is saved to capture group 2. It does not seem necessary to ensure that the line saved to capture group 1 is preceded by a line of equal signs.

The `m` flag must be set, causing the anchors `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of a line (rather than the beginning and end of the string).

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/XNPrbI/1)

The expression can be broken down as follows.

```
^                   # match the beginning of the line    
(.*\n)              # match a line and save to capture group 1
=+                  # match '=' one or more times
\s+                 # match one or more whitespaces
(                   # begin capture group 2
  (?:\d+ +.*\n)     # match one or more digits followed by one or more spaces,
                    # followed by the rest of the line
  +                 # execute the preceding non-capture group 1 or more times
)                   # end capture group 2
```

Comment: Most of the time `\r` or `\r?` is redundant except for this part `=+\r?\n`. For example, when you write `.*\r?\n` the `\r?` will never succeed because the dot matches the carriage return and has a greedy quantifier, same thing with `\s*\r?\n`. Also in `[^\s\d=\r\n]`, the carriage return and the line feed are already contained in `\s`.

Comment: Thank you, @CasimiretHippolyte. I was unaware that a dot matches `'\r'`.

Comment: I wasn't sure too and I tested it, because the dot matches `\r` by default in PHP (due to the default setting `(*LF)`) but not in nodeJS where `/./.test("\r")` returns `false`.